# Can't find solution for conveyor belt Coding Challenge

Tags: javascript

------ Coding Challenge ------

> There is a factory production line around a single a conveyor belt.
>
> Components (of type A and B) come onto the start of the belt at random
> intervals; workers must take one component of each type from the belt
> as they come past, and combine them to make a finished product.
>
> The belt is divided into fixed-size slots; each slot can hold only one
> component or one finished product.  There are a number of worker
> stations on either side of the belt, spaced to match the size of the
> slots on the belt, like this (fixed-width font ASCII pic):
>
> ```
>        v   v   v   v   v          workers
>      ---------------------
>   -> | A |   | B | A | P | ->     conveyor belt
>      ---------------------
>        ^   ^   ^   ^   ^          workers
> ```
>
> In each unit of time, the belt moves forwards one position, and there
> is time for a worker on one side of each slot to EITHER take an item
> from the slot or replace an item onto the belt.  The worker opposite
> them can't touch the same belt slot while they do this. (So you can't
> have one worker picking something from a slot while  their counterpart
> puts something down in the same place).
>
> Once a worker has collected one of both types of component, they can
> begin assembling the finished product.  This takes an amount of time,
> so they will only be ready to place the assembled product back on the
> belt on the fourth subsequent slot.  While they are assembling the
> product, they can't touch the conveyor belt.  Workers can only hold
> two items (component or product) at a time: one in each hand.
>
> Create a simulation of this, with three pairs of workers.  At each
> time interval, the slot at the start of the conveyor belt should have
> an equal (1/3) chance of containing nothing, a component A or a
> component B.
>
> Run the simulation for 100 steps, and compute how many finished
> products come off the production line, and how many components of each
> type go through the production line without being picked up by any
> workers.
>
> A few pointers:
>
> - You should expect to spend no more than two or three hours on this    challenge.
> - The code does not have to be 'production quality', but    we will be looking for evidence that it's written to be    somewhat flexible,
>   and that a third party would be able to    read and maintain it.
> - Be sure to state (or comment) your assumptions.
> - During the interview, we may ask about the effect of changing  certain    aspects of the simulation. (E.g. the length of the conveyor
>   belt.)
> - Flexibility in the solution is preferred, but we are also looking     for a sensible decision on where this adds too much complexity.
>   (Where would it be better to rewrite the code for a different
>   scenario, rather than spending much more than the allotted time
>   creating an overly complicated, but very flexible simulation engine?)

so I came across this coding challenge on a forum from 2010, from searching google I have found solutions but only in C++ and PHP when I only know JavaScript.

I don't suppose anyone could show me how to at least approach the problem?

Comment: Please add attribution. From where did you copy this challenge text?

Comment: Can you link those C++ and PHP solutions, please? And even without understanding the details in those languages, the approach should be the same?

Answer (score 0):

A small unfinished (read not nicely wrapped and stored into functions or classes) approach.

The main part is inside of the worker's update, where the order is to check

- if has to wait, wait and decrement waiting time, exit,
- if can build product, finish product, exit,
- if is not allowed to take action from belt, exit,
- if slot is empty, check if product is ready and move it to belt, prevent further action of same slot worker,
- if slot has product or no hands free, exit.
- if side does not have this component, take it,

  - prevent further action of same slot worker,
  - if a product is producible, start producing/start waiting

The output shows

```
|   20 | _ A B | U:B_0 L:P_0 | U:BA3 L:B_0 | U:B_0 L:B_0 | P _ B |

    1      2          3             3             3          4
```

which means

1. Step.
2. Belt before workers work.
3. Slot 1 ... 3 with upper and lower worker, as well their hands with components or product and waiting time.
4. Belt after workers work.

And the wanted statistical data

```
{
    P: 23,
    B: 10
}
```

Which has in this case `23` products and `10` left over component `B`.

```js
const
    out = document.getElementById('out'),
    print = (...args) => out.innerHTML += args.join(' '),

    EMPTY = '_',
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B',
    COMPONENTS = [A, B],
    PRODUCT = 'P',
    HANDS = 2,
    length = 3,
    belt = Array(length).fill(EMPTY),
    values = [EMPTY, ...COMPONENTS],
    product = [[A, 1], [B, 1]],
    isProducible = components => {
        const counts = components.reduce((r, type) => (r[type] = (r[type] || 0) + 1, r), {});
        return product.every(([type, count]) => counts[type] >= count);
    },
    result = {},
    workers = Array.from(
        { length },
        () => ({
            upper: { items: [], wait: 0 },
            lower: { items: [], wait: 0 }
        })
    ),
    getWorker = ({ upper, lower }) => [upper, lower].map(({ items, wait }, i) => ['UL'[i], ':', items.join('').padEnd(2, '_'), wait].join('')).join(' ');

print('| Step | Belt  |   Slot 1    |   Slot 2    |   Slot 3    | Belt  |\n');
print('|======|=======|=============|=============|=============|=======| \n');

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const last = belt.pop();
    if (last !== EMPTY) result[last] = (result[last] || 0) + 1;
    belt.unshift(values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)]);
    const top = ['|', i.toString().padStart(4, ' '), '|', ...belt].join(' ');

    const taken = [];
    workers.forEach(({ upper, lower }, i) => {
        const
            update = side => {
                if (side.wait) return --side.wait;
                if (isProducible(side.items)) side.items = [PRODUCT];
                if (taken[i]) return;
                if (belt[i] === EMPTY) {
                    if (side.items[0] === PRODUCT) {
                        belt[i] = side.items.shift();
                        taken[i] = true;
                    }
                    return;
                }
                if (belt[i] === PRODUCT || side.items.length === HANDS) return;
                if (!side.items.includes(belt[i])) {
                    side.items.push(belt[i]);
                    belt[i] = EMPTY;
                    taken[i] = true;
                    if (isProducible(side.items)) side.wait = 3;
                }
            };

        update(upper);
        update(lower);       
    });


    print(top, '|', workers.map(getWorker).join(' | '), '|', ...belt, '|', '\n');
}

print('\n' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```